# CoreBluetooth connect to peripheral in background on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-bluetooth, iphone-6

I have an app that connects to BLE devices in background (after discovering them).
Just tested it on iPhone 6 and found out that the app can't re-connect peripherals when it's in the background (as it used to on iPhone 5S and below).

I'm running same app on iPhone 5S and iPhone 6, side by side, just a few inches from each other, both running iOS 8.0.2.
iPhone 5S - connects to peripherals, iPhone 6 - does not.
Peripheral advertises in 500ms interval.

i'm using CBCentralManger connectPeripheral method.

Could it be an iPhone 6 HW,
Should I change advertising interval?
Has anyone tried to run CBCentralManger scan or connect peripheral in background on iPhone 6?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: :/ .. after checking your question i guess . i have to buy iPhone6 for testing my app which uses `CBCentralManger ` .. let me know if you find a solution !

Comment: I read [an article](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/01/ios-8-bluetooth-connectivity-issues/) the other day that said some iPhones 6 / iOS 8 devices where having issues connecting to bluetooth. I'm not sure if that extends to BLE devices as well but it's possible.